# make button clickable below recycler view

Tags: android

Hi I have a layout as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.widgets.AppSwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.widgets.AppRecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/test"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|start|center_vertical"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:text="TEST" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </com.widgets.AppSwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My recycler view has 2 types of items, 1 is a regular item, 1 an item with transparent background to show the button. My problem is, when transparent item is screen and button is visible, button doesn't receive click events. I thought it's probably because of elevation and changed elevation, but it didn't solve the issue. How can I make button to receive click events?

Comment: set the transparent items visibility to GONE and try

Comment: @PembaTamang your suggestion hides the area that's requeired to show the button.

Comment: there is a function called bringToFront  for any type of view I guess that should work

Comment: I used it a long time back I don't remember... you can look into it

Comment: @PembaTamang bringToFront  just brings the view above recycler view, and it stays there anymore. Button should remain below the recycler view, and can only be clickable when it's under transparent item. (When the button is visible)

Comment: I cannt understand what u want post a screenshot